# Generate High Quality Thumbnail Images from PDF Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I'm able to generate the pdf thumbnail images from PDF document. But the problem is i'm getting `white space` on top and bottom of the image and also I changed the  `X Y coordinate` values but it didn't worked for me.

And also i'm getting `low qualit`y images means those images are not looking good.

In `iBook`, pdf thumbnail images are looks too good. So i want to generate that kind of thumbnail images.

Here is the Code..

```
-(NSMutableArray *)generateThumbnail:(NSMutableArray *)arrayDocuments
{
    NSMutableArray* arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayDocuments count]; i++) {

        NSString* fileName = [arrayDocuments objectAtIndex:i];

         NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];

        NSURL* pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);

        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 0 + 1);

        CGRect aRect =CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        UIImage* thumbnailImage;

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);


        CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, aRect, 0, true);

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

        thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        [arrayOfImages addObject:thumbnailImage];

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
    }

    return arrayOfImages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, It will improve quality. It creates images with the scale of screen/device which is 2.0 for iPhone 5 series and 3.0 for iPhone 6 plus i guess.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ( aRect.size , NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

Below uses scale factor of 1 by default thats why the quality is low.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);